# Get VoIP info from other apps

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, phone-call

I need in my service to find the difference between a call from CS (Circuit Switch) and others calls, like Hangout, Viber, whatsapp, and others apps.

Can you give me some tips to follow?

Comment: You want to know the diff. between VoIP calls (used by Hangout, Viber) and Telephonic calls? `NotificationListenerService`  receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed. So it will be no use to you. Can you make your question more explicit...what exactly you need?

Comment: Hi @MeTechnical, I really need to write in a log or something the count of incoming calls, differencing the source, like this:
Circuits Switch: 33 calls
Skype: 12 calls
Hangout: 5 calls
Viber: 2 calls

I have already a service to read the calls. I'll try getting the package name of the incomming call intent, maybe that's the key to do this.

About NotificationListenerService is not supported in the version i need to compile.

Thanks again for your support!

Regards!

Comment: @MeTechnical maybe I can get in my service the last activity open(name, package, or something related to the aplication in course), so, like I saw in the LogCat, if I get something like this: '02-23 16:40:43.714: I/ActivityManager(2300): Displayed com.viber.voip/.phone.PhoneFragmentActivity: +123ms (total +219ms)' I know this is an viber call.
can you give me some tips or some web to read an example about that...Right now i'm in a blank point...my mind is in a collapse..LOL